# Wireless Interfaces with Asus Z270-AR and Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, bios

I've just put together my computer with the following:
 - Asus PRIME Z270-AR
 - Intel i5-7600K
 - 8GB Corsair Vengeance DDR4
 - 240GB PNY SSD

It's currently got Ubuntu 16.10 working on it, and the ethernet connection works fine (after enabling LAN in the BIOS), but it cannot connect to my wireless connection. I've tried disabling/enabling a few network-related settings in the BIOS, all to no avail.

Has anyone experienced this issue? What setting must be enabled to get a wireless interface? It isn't even listed in the output of:

> lshw -C network

```
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 00
   serial: 2c:4d:54:55:6a:db
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.2-4 ip=10.0.0.137 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:127 memory:df100000-df11ffff
```